# disable css classes using jquery just like with firebug, is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I get the effect that I want using firebug; I disable this:

```
.ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a {
color:#030303;
}
```

(actually I only need to disable `.ui-state-highlight a {color:#030303}`)
how could I do this using jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override styles using JQuery [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method, but probably the cleanest solution is to host your own version of jquery-ui stylesheet locally and change it whenever necessary.

Or, as **revaxarts** noted, you can override value with `!important` directive.

Comment: I didn't explained everything in details, but I solved my problem by doing: $('.ui-state-highlight a').css('color', $('.ui-state-default').css('color'));

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-state-highlight a {color:auto !important;}
```

sorry, couldn't test it

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if I understand your need correctly, but first you need to select your element, I'll assume here you want to apply this to every `<a>` in your code. To remove a class from a set of elements you can use `.removeClass()`

```
$('a').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

If it's just the color that needs removing you could remove that particular css in place.

```
$('a').css('color', '#000');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$('.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('.ui-state-highlight');
```